# Remove one div if another is empty

Tags: jquery, html, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get one div to show if another is empty. This needs to happen multiple times throughout a page. The script won't work in its present state.

Script:

```
$('.standard_page_list_result').each(function(){

if ($('.children p').length == 0)
    $('.summary').css("display", "block");

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="standard_page_list_result"><div class="children"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="summary"><p>Goodbye</p></div></div>

<div class="standard_page_list_result"><div class="children"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="summary"><p>Goodbye</p></div></div>

<div class="standard_page_list_result"><div class="children"><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="summary"><p>Goodbye</p></div></div>

<div class="standard_page_list_result"><div class="children"><p></p></div>
<div class="summary"><p>Hello!</p></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.summary { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your same concept, you need to identify the one your in with `this` and then do a find selector in order to make it work. what you were doing was getting the length of all.

```
$('.standard_page_list_result').each(function(){
    if ($(this).find('.children p').text().length == 0)
        $(this).find('.summary').css("display", "block");
});
```

Here is the jsFiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaPack/4C35E/

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! And thank you to everyone else, stackoverflow peeps rule :D

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
$('.standard_page_list_result .children p:empty').parent().next('.summary').css('display','block');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JXDNk/

Comment: +1 That is a great way of doing it! Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the length of the `<div>` try using the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function.

```
$('.standard_page_list_result').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('.children p').is(':empty')) {
      $(this).find('.summary').css("display", "block");
   }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed the code above to select each element rather than affecting all elements if only 1 was empty.  Other answer already chosen but for future viewers this is the alternative with using the is() function.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt5Zn/) for it.

Note: empty checks for no white-space too.  If there's a single space, then it's not empty

Comment: Thanks @JT Smith, that's working. But is the 'each' parameter declared correctly in the script I provided? Because if the first .child div is empty, every other .summary div on the page seems to show.

Comment: Yes, the wrapper `each()` function appears to be fine to me.  Is it still not working when you change your length test with what I provided?

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle the summary based on the emptiness of the elements:

```
$('.standard_page_list_result').each(function(){
  $('.summary', this).toggle( $('.children p', this).is(":empty") );
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('...').length` will tell you how many elements matched your selector, not if those elements are empty.

To check if the element is empty, I would probably do it like this:

```
if($.trim($(...).text()).length == 0)
```

Finally, you'll need to use `this` inside your each to target the appropriate elements.  Something like this:

```
$('.standard_page_list_result').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($.trim($this.find('.children p').text()).length == 0){
        $this.find('.summary').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzfGL/1/